# Check if array of string A has letters that exist in array of string B (Not working)

Tags: c, arrays, char, compare

my program currently has two strings, one which gets the user input from the users sentence he's entering (ASCI only) and the other is certain letters that i chose to compare the two strings with. My problem is that with using strncmp(), I'm trying to see if letters from the user input exist in the second array, and if they do, print "success", however when I run my program it appears to always print the noMatch function, even if i enter every letter present in my second array! Any help would be much appreciated!

Here is a snippet:

```
int main (void)
{
    char letters[6] = {'a','b','c','d','e'};
    char userInput[6];

    printf("Enter a sentence! ASCII characters only!");
    fgets(userInput,6,stdin);

    doLettersMatch(userInput,letters);

}

void doLettersMatch(char userInput[], char letters[])
{
    int i;
    for(i=0;i<6;i++)
    {
       if(strcmp(&userInput[i],&letters[i]) != 0) //i.e letters don't match
       noMatch();
    }

    printf("success! the letters matched from the user input");
}

int noMatch()
{

    printf("No letters matched!");
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Why do you use strcmp to compare two char? Why not simply doing if (userInput[i] == letters[i])

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your function should be:

```
void doLettersMatch(char userInput[], char letters[])
{
    int i;
    for(i=0;i<6;i++)
    {
       if(userInput[i] == letters[i]) {
           ++found;
           printf("success! the letters matched from the user input");
           return;
       }
    }
    noMatch();
}
```

`strcmp` compares 2 strings and not letters. `strcmp(&userInput[i],&letters[i])` will compare the substrings at offset `i`.

If you want to match the characters irrespective of the positions, use the following

```
void doLettersMatch(char userInput[], char letters[])
{
    int i;
    int j;
    for(i=0;i<6;i++)
    {
       for(j = 0; userInput[j] != '\0'; ++j) {
           if(userInput[j] == letters[i]) {
               ++found;
               printf("success! the letters matched from the user input");
               return;
           }
       }
    }
    noMatch();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

This works for me (I think you dont want to compare the last char (\0)?) , as rusol said, comparing every char of the UserInput. It prints the position of the characters that are equal in both arrays:

```
void doLettersMatch(char userInput[], char letters[])
{
    int i;
    for (i = 0; i<6; i++)
    {
        if (userInput[i] == letters[i]){
            printf("The character %c exists in both strings! Position: %d\n", letters[i], i);
        }
    }
}

int main(void)
{
    char letters[6] = { 'a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f' };
    char userInput[6];

    printf("Enter a sentence! ASCII characters only!\n");
    fgets(userInput, 6, stdin);

    doLettersMatch(userInput, letters);
    return 0;
}
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: unfortunately, this doesn't solve my problem as when i enter a single character that exists in the second array, it goes straight to your second print statement. I only want this to happen if ALL characters coexist between the user input and the second array not just one.

Comment: If i understand you well, the characters must be in the same position?

I edited the code in the response, check it!